# Looking for a collaborative drawing solution

Tags: online-instruction

Preparing for a class I teach this summer and stumbled upon a technology problem.

I want to show my students a graph, ask students to annotate it privately (eg mark mean on a histogram) and then overlay all of their images with the true mean to show the distribution of their guesses. Is there an implemented solution?

Comment: Is tracing paper too old school? https://www.amazon.com/Tracing-Paper/b?ie=UTF8&node=12898291

Comment: @guest I was going to suggest something like this as well, but it seems like the OP is specifically asking for technological solutions, since it is tagged as "online-instruction."

Comment: learningcatalytics.com has that functionality

Answer (score 3):

I'm the only person in my department who hasn't gone deep into Nearpod, but it seemed in training that this was part of their appeal.  If you couldn't overlay all of their estimates simultaneously, you could certainly display each one in rapid succession.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using zoom, I think you might be able to display your graph on the whiteboard and have them all annotate. If not, there are many online whiteboards available for collaboration. A colleague recently recommended app.ziteboard.com. (I haven't tried it out yet.)

Comment: Yes, Zoom can allow for this, and you could make the annotations anonymous too!

Answer (score 3):

Desmos classroom activities are capable of doing this sort of thing. https://teacher.desmos.com

There are lots of existing activities you can copy that might do the exact thing you want.

(The front page mentions setting up “classrooms”. You don’t have to create classrooms to use Desmos activities as far as I know. Pretty sure you can still have a stand-alone activity the students sign into just with their names.)